# Post on somebody else’s page

Tags: facebook

I've written birthday posts on a friend’s page, but they don't show up. Where did they go? And how do I find them and bring them up?

Answer (score 2):

If you post to a friend's timeline the day of his birthday, your post will appear in a special box on the timeline.

> 91 friends posted on your timeline for your birthday.

[image]

---

If you can't find it, you can use the "View friendship" feature to find all the relations between you and him:

[image]